# Open java applet in chrome

Tags: java, applet

I was wondering how to open a locally stored java applet in chrome or edge. I was using the IE tab extension and it doesn't seem to work on locally stored applets. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to have a read of [this](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml), [this](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml) and possibly [this](http://superuser.com/questions/902575/how-to-re-enable-java-plugin-on-google-chrome-42-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think Chrome supports plugins anymore, but you could use internet explorer and just enable scripting of java applets.

Comment: i try in ie but a local aplet wont open. Everything else works fine